# Temporary operation in a temporary directory in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, temporary-files, temporary-directory

I need a fresh temporary directory to do some work in a shell script. When the work is done (or if I kill the job midway), I want the script to change back to the old working directory and wipe out the temporary one. In Ruby, it might look like this:

```
require 'tmpdir'

Dir.mktmpdir 'my_build' do |temp_dir|
  puts "Temporary workspace is #{temp_dir}"
  do_some_stuff(temp_dir)
end

puts "Temporary directory already deleted"
```

What would be the best bang for the buck to do that in a Bash script?

Here is my current implementation. Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
here=$( pwd )
tdir=$( mktemp -d )
trap 'return_here' INT TERM EXIT
return_here () {
    cd "$here"
    [ -d "$tdir" ] && rm -rf "$tdir"
}

do_stuff # This may succeed, fail, change dir, or I may ^C it.
return_here
```

Comment: You can use 'cd -' to return to the previous directory. That way you don't have to save the name of the old directory. Another option would be to use pushd/popd.

Comment: I explicitly stored the directory to give `do_stuff` freedom to change directory, change the pushd queue, etc. However in my case I know `do_stuff` doesn't use pushd/popd so that would be a much nicer implementation!

Comment: I would not trust `cd -` (the script may have `cd`-ed multiple places before the trap runs).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
TDIR=`mktemp -d`

trap "{ cd - ; rm -rf $TDIR; exit 255; }" SIGINT

cd $TDIR
# do important stuff here
cd -

rm -rf $TDIR

exit 0
```

Comment: You can add EXIT to your trap and you won't have to do the explicit `rm`.

Comment: Thanks! That's a good pattern. I updated my question with my own version. I have not been exiting 255 like that though.

Answer (score 1):

The usual utility to get yourself a temporary directory is `mktemp -d` (and the `-p` option lets you specify a prefix directory).

I'm not sure if "I want to trap" was a question too, but bash does let you trap signals with (surprise!) `trap` - see the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use the components. I am asking around for people's preferred ways of putting them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `mktemp -d` returns a relative pathname, I would forget about `$here` and do this instead:

```
tdir=
cleanup() {
    test -n "$tdir" && test -d "$tdir" && rm -rf "$tdir"
}
tdir="$(pwd)/$(mktemp -d)"
trap cleanup EXIT
trap 'cleanup; exit 127' INT TERM

# no need to call cleanup explicitly, unless the shell itself crashes, the EXIT trap will run it for you
```

Comment: Could you please explain why are you using two traps?